# Want to open camera directly in html5-qrcode (reactjs)

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, html5-qrcode

I am facing issue on mobile I am not able to open camera directly there is a text name "start scanning" user needs to click that button to open camera and start ,is there any way to open camera directly without click on start scanning button on mobile , I forcefully did it on web using Dom that's working fine

Want to open camera ditectly without click on text "start scanning"..

This is our current code

```
import { Html5QrcodeScanner } from "html5-qrcode";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const qrcodeRegionId = "html5qr-code-full-region";

// Creates the configuration object for Html5QrcodeScanner.
const createConfig = (props) => {
  let config = {};
  if (props.fps) {
    config.fps = props.fps;
  }
  if (props.qrbox) {
    config.qrbox = props.qrbox;
  }
  if (props.aspectRatio) {
    config.aspectRatio = props.aspectRatio;
  }
  if (props.disableFlip !== undefined) {
    config.disableFlip = props.disableFlip;
  }
  return config;
};

const Html5QrcodePlugin = (props) => {
  const [text, setText] = useState(false);

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   let inner = document.getElementById("html5-qrcode-anchor-scan-type-change");
  //   if (inner?.innerHTML == "Scan using camera directly") {
  //     inner.innerHTML = "";
  //   }
  // });
  useEffect(() => {
    // when component mounts
    const config = createConfig(props);
    const verbose = props.verbose === true;
    // Suceess callback is required.
    if (!props.qrCodeSuccessCallback) {
      throw "qrCodeSuccessCallback is required callback.";
    }
    const html5QrcodeScanner = new Html5QrcodeScanner(
      qrcodeRegionId,
      config,
      verbose
    );
    html5QrcodeScanner.render(
      props.qrCodeSuccessCallback,
      props.qrCodeErrorCallback
    );

    // cleanup function when component will unmount
    return () => {
      html5QrcodeScanner.clear().catch((error) => {
        console.error("Failed to clear html5QrcodeScanner. ", error);
      });
    };
  }, []);

  return <div id={qrcodeRegionId} onClick={() => setText(!text)} />;
};

export default Html5QrcodePlugin;
```

Comment: Could you describe what 'I forcefully did it on web using Dom ' means? I didn't know you could access the camera without user interaction.